# I can't find a way to fetch my generated e-sign from Docusign

Tags: php, docusignapi

I have created an e-sign on Docusign website and generated an integrator key through website.But i can't find a way to fetch my generated e-sign from Docusign back to my local machine.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow :) People are encouraged to try something before asking for a direct solution here. What did you already try? Also, please take a look here: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You want to download a signed document from DocuSign to your application?

Use the getDocument call for that. API docs: [EnvelopeDocuments::get](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get)

Here's [example code](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant/blob/master/lib/examples/eg007EnvelopeGetDoc.js) for Node.js. PHP examples are in the pipeline.

If you have trouble, please ask another question on stack overflow. Include the relevant code from your application.